# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value mysql error

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete multiple rows with checkboxes, php and sql, and here is my code for that:

```
<?php
include_once("../../files/connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['val']))
{
    $p = &$_POST['val'];
    foreach($p as &$v)
    {
        $v = "'". mysqli_escape_string($kapcs, $v) ."'";
    }
    $values = '('.implode(',',$p).')';
    $sql = "DELETE FROM elony WHERE elony_id IN $values";
    
    print_r($sql);
    
    
    mysqli_query($kapcs, $sql) or die("SQL ERROR - " . mysqli_error($kapcs));
    
    echo 'A kijelölt sorok törölve lettek az adatbázisból.';
}
else
{
    exit("Nem jelölt ki egyetlen sort sem.");
}
?>
```

My problem is, that i always get this error: )SQL ERROR - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'on'

If i echo out my query, it looks like: DELETE FROM elony WHERE elony_id IN ('on','3','4')
Whats that 'on'? How does it get into the query?

Comment: *Whats that 'on'?* It is taken from `$p`. Check your `$_POST['val']` value.

Comment: The $p gives back this: 3,4, so thats correct.

Comment: Nevertheless imploding gives this 'on' present in `$values`.

Comment: And what should i modify in the code?

Comment: You have tagged the question as MySQL-relative only. Does you need in solution on MySQL side staying PHP code wrong?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will invariably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: How did it get there? You put it there somehow. It didn't just show up. You'll need to `var_dump()` and track it down.